# Achieve If statement in where clause in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check a condition in a where clause

```
Select * from [Sale Master] where 
IF (@IsTime='1')
BEGIN
convert(char(19),Sale_Date,20) between'2016-05-18 10:45:00' and '2016-05-18 10:55:00'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
convert(char(10),Sale_Date,20) between'2016-05-18' and '2016-05-18'
END
```

what I am actually trying to do is I want to search record based on the `@IsTime` bit variable.If it is true the it should considers the date along with time otherwise it considers only date alone.I know that IF condition should not be used in Where Clause but I don't have any Idea about using CASE.

Comment: You don't really need the quotes around `bit` values.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an `if()` -- nor a `case`.  More importantly, though:  there is no reason to convert dates to strings for comparison.  So:

```
Select *
from [Sale Master]
where (@IsTime = '1' and sale_date between '2016-05-18 10:45:00' and '2016-05-18 10:55:00') or
      (@IsTime <> '1' and Sale_Date between '2016-05-18' and '2016-05-18');
```

Note:  if `IsTime` is a number, then do no use quotes for the comparison.  Also, if the value can be `NULL`, then the second comparison needs to take that into account.

Actually, it can be dangerous to use `between` with date/times.  I prefer direct comparisons:

```
Select *
from [Sale Master]
where (@IsTime = '1' and sale_date >= '2016-05-18 10:45:00' and sale_date < '2016-05-18 10:55:00') or
      (@IsTime <> '1' and Sale_Date >= '2016-05-18' and Sale_Date < '2016-05-19');
```

Aaron Bertrand has a [good blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) explaining issues with using `between` for date/times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select * 
from [Sale Master] 
where 
(
   (@IsTime=1) 
   and 
   convert(char(19),Sale_Date,20) between '2016-05-18 10:45:00' and '2016-05-18 10:55:00'
) 
or          
(
   (@IsTime=0) 
   and 
   convert(char(10),Sale_Date,20) between '2016-05-18' and '2016-05-18'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this is somewhat similar to Gordon Linoff post but I removed a condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sale Master]
WHERE (
        @IsTime = '1'
        AND sale_date BETWEEN '2016-05-18 10:45:00'
            AND '2016-05-18 10:55:00'
        )
    OR (
        Sale_Date BETWEEN '2016-05-18'
            AND '2016-05-18'
        );
```

Comment: @Tanner: Explain me why so that I can understand

Comment: Firstly, the second clause will be evaluated regardless of the value of `@IsTime`. Secondly, the clause with the date check has the same value, so there is no between. Perhaps test it and see what your code does against dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (@IsTime='1')
BEGIN
     Select * from [Sale Master] 
     where convert(char(19),Sale_Date,20) between'2016-05-18 10:45:00' and '2016-05-18 10:55:00'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     Select * from [Sale Master]
     where convert(char(10),Sale_Date,20) between'2016-05-18' and '2016-05-18'
END
```